# Android Periodic WorkManager not triggering

Tags: android, backgroundworker, android-workmanager

This periodic work manager task does not appear to execute. 
For testing I have stripped down the `googleFitHelper.syncData` method below to have it only access a url (post) using the `Volley` framework.

The `manifest` has  `android.permission.INTERNET` set. 
The `manifest` has no other parameters related to the `workmanager` task.

To test I am writing a log on the server when the url is accessed.

Am I missing something?

Note: The task functions as expected as a `OneTimeWorkRequest`.

```
class MainActivty {
    ...

    private void scheduleSyncJobService(){
        SyncWorkManagerUtility syncWorkManagerUtility = new SyncWorkManagerUtility();
        syncWorkManagerUtility.scheduleJob();
    }
}



class SyncWorkManagerUtility {
    private static final String TAG = SyncWorkManagerUtility.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String SYNC_WORK_JOB1 = "SYNC_WORK_JOB1";

    void scheduleJob() {
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build();

    PeriodicWorkRequest syncRequest =
        new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(SyncWorkManagerService.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addTag(SYNC_WORK_JOB1)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build();
            Log.d(TAG, "Scheduling Job " + SYNC_WORK_JOB1);
            WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(SYNC_WORK_JOB1, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, syncRequest);
    }
}


public class SyncWorkManagerService extends Worker {
    ...

    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        GoogleFitHelper googleFitHelper = new GoogleFitHelper(getApplicationContext());
        googleFitHelper.syncData();
        return Result.success();
    }
}

public class GoogleFitHelper {
    ....

    void syncData(){
        String url="https://example.com/testbackgroundtask.php";
        StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        responseString -> {},
        error -> {}) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("testdataA", "testdataA");
                params.put("testdataB", "testdataB");
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
            }
    };
    VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(strRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a asynchronous request in a synchronous Worker. Try using ListenableWorker instead.

Comment: Are you referencing the http request?  This worker is not interested in a response from the http request.  It sends the request and moves on. If I replace doWork with do nothing (sleep) code it never fires. My issue is that the PeriodicWorkRequest does not appear to execute. If I query the WorkManager it does show the task as scheduled.

Comment: In the end it was my own issue. I had inadvertently allowed lint to change the scope of the SyncWorkManagerService  class from public to package and the class could not be instantiated (found) within the scope of the work manager.